# Can you figure out how we're related?

Tags: family

Here is the puzzle:

> If Teresa's daughter is my daughter's mother,
>   What am I to Teresa?

Find  puzzle [here](https://twitter.com/etribune/status/822374760180916224)

Comment: This question has appeared on many sites before and you should credit the original to avoid plagiarism.

Comment: @QaisarSatti it is probably not a duplicate on this website per say. Techidiot only meant that this is a well known puzzle which deserve some references. Unless you want to claim you made that puzzle yourself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only 100% correct answer I can think of is

> You are the parent of her grand child.

Explanation

> Son in law assume that you are married. Which you might not be.
>  It is also possible that you are simply Teresa's daughter. Why not.

Comment: It is also possible that you are simply Teresa's daughter how?

Comment: @QaisarSatti "My daughter's mother" can be describing the mother herself.

Answer (score 4):

You are

> Teressa's Daughter

Reason

> "Teresa's daughter is my daughter's mother"
>  my daughter's mother is actually me (i.e. the person who is asking the puzzle).
>
>    Therefore:
>
>  Teresa's daughter is me (i.e. the person who is asking the puzzle is    Teresa's daughter).
>  
>  Note: As there are only females available for the answer, the answer cannot be a male.
>
>  [Credit](https://www.brainbashers.com/showpuzzles.asp?puzzle=ZEZV)

Another simpler explanation

> *Teresa* - > *Daugter* -> **X** -> *is My Daugter's Mother* -> **Me**
>
>  Hence *X = Me*
>  Hence, ***I am Teresa's Daughter***

Comment: In your source, only females are available. But not in OP's questions. so the father is also viable.

Comment: @stackreader That's right but it's a valid answer as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You are Teresa's

> Son in law

Because

> your wife is Teresa's daughter

Answer (score 1):

You are:

> Her son-in-law. Her daughter, your wife, is the mother of YOUR daughter.

Answer (score 1):

There are are only two solution-answers to this puzzle.

1.

> I am married to Teresa's daughter then I am the son-in-law of Teresa. If I was ever married and I am no more I am an ex-son-in-law.

2.

> I had my daughter out of wedlock, then Teresa is simply my daughter's maternal grandmother.

Answer (score 0):

You are

> Teresa's SON in LAW, because your wife is Teresa's daughter.